# Change Status Bar Colour in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using Chrome Custom Tabs to display web content in my app. Obviously one of the main advantages of this is the ability to change UI colours in the tab. However, I need to change the status bar colour to something other than a darker version of the primary colour I provide.

Is there anyway to do this?

For reference, here is my code as it stands.

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
builder.setToolbarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
builder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(url));
```

As you can probably guess, I want to change the status bar colour to `R.color.colorPrimary` rather than the automatically selected colour.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now, you cannot change the status bar color when using Custom Tabs. You can check it by yourself from the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/c502e63/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.java) of `CustomTabsIntent.Builder` to see what you can customize or see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html).

I don't try it by myself yet, but if you are targeting api >= 21 (Lollipop), I think the following code could be a work around.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setStatusBarColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
}

private void setStatusBarColor(int colorId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorId));
}

private void showUrl(String url) {
    setStatusBarColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    yourCustomTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
}
```